# Web role stops immediately in azure emulator

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-emulator

I'm trying to get azure web role working in the emulator.

I believe I and my colleague are using exactly the same setup. But it works on my machine but not on hers.

Here is the setup:
Visual Studio 2015 Community.
Azure SDK 2.9.5.

I've compared the logs, mine looks like this:

```
....  
State of xx changed from RoleStateSuspended to RoleStateBusy.
State of xx changed from RoleStateBusy to RoleStateUnhealthy.
State of xx changed from RoleStateUnhealthy to RoleStateBusy.
State of xx changed from RoleStateBusy to RoleStateStarted.  
....
```

And hers looks like this:

```
....
State of xx changed from RoleStateSuspended to RoleStateBusy.
State of xx changed from RoleStateBusy to RoleStateUnhealthy.
>>>>_Context_Start: {7A692122-8B13-42A8-8B8B-435872E2C0C3}      Context={{ StopRoleEx:  instanceId=xx }}
>>>>_Context_Start: {C882D389-A2C9-47F2-9A05-6E23F56157B6}      Context={{ AgentpStopRoleWorkerEx:  ContainerId=EmulatorContainer   RoleInstanceId=xx }}
<- AgentMonitoringObject::EventStart(0x00007FF95DD075A0) =0x80070015        Context={{ AgentpStopRoleWorkerEx:  ContainerId=EmulatorContainer   RoleInstanceId=xx }}
Stopping role: xx. Notify: True  Recycle: False  StopTimeout: 5     Context={{ AgentpStopRoleWorkerEx:  ContainerId=EmulatorContainer   RoleInstanceId=xx }}
State of xx changed from RoleStateUnhealthy to RoleStateStopping.       Context={{ AgentpStopRoleWorkerEx:  ContainerId=EmulatorContainer   RoleInstanceId=xx }}
....
```

The question is what could possibly casue the web role to go into the stopping state?

My theory is that 'StopTimeout: 5' might be the issue here. But how do I change this value?

Comment: Where can you see these logs?

Comment: @Piedone, can't remember now. Pretty sure just googled.

Comment: Did the same but after a lot of digging I only get to outdated paths and empty log folders. In the end I discovered one log that may actually contains something useful, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41926079/220230